# Nginx install don't work

Tags: nginx, apt, dpkg

I have a problem with nginx , I deleted nginx because I did some modifications in nginx.conf and now I can't install it ...

```
apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libmemcached11 libmemcachedutil2
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  nginx-common nginx-full
Suggested packages:
  fcgiwrap nginx-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nginx-common nginx-full
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/518 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1311 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 122283 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nginx-common_1.6.2-5+deb8u4_all.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-common (1.6.2-5+deb8u4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-common_1.6.2-5+deb8                                                                                                                                                             u4_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/nginx/scgi_params', which is also in package sw-nginx                                                                                                                                                              1.11.10-debian8.0.17040416
Preparing to unpack .../nginx-full_1.6.2-5+deb8u4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-full (1.6.2-5+deb8u4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-full_1.6.2-5+deb8u4                                                                                                                                                             _amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/nginx', which is also in package sw-nginx 1.11.1                                                                                                                                                             0-debian8.0.17040416
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-common_1.6.2-5+deb8u4_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-full_1.6.2-5+deb8u4_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@vps:~# apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nginx : Depends: nginx-full (>= 1.6.2-5+deb8u4) but it is not installed or
                  nginx-light (>= 1.6.2-5+deb8u4) but it is not installed or
                  nginx-extras (>= 1.6.2-5+deb8u4) but it is not installed
         Depends: nginx-full (< 1.6.2-5+deb8u4.1~) but it is not installed or
                  nginx-light (< 1.6.2-5+deb8u4.1~) but it is not installed or
                  nginx-extras (< 1.6.2-5+deb8u4.1~) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Comment: The easiest way is to restore from your backup. Alternately you may be able to try using apt to remove the packages that it thinks are still there. I've had to do things like this in the past, I muddled through, but it's fiddly.

Comment: The correct way to uninstall software in Debian / Ubuntu is `apt-get remove`. Other ways will give you issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try and run the following commands

```
sudo apt-get remove nginx && sudo apt-get purge nginx
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

purge delete configuration files for an application, but if it isin't removed first this gives issues.

**&&** only executes if previous command executed, exited with exit code 0 (successfull) `echo $?` will show you the exit code of an application.

If all of this fails try and run `dpkg -l|grep nginx` and look for the first two letters in the output to see the status of the nginx package installation.

Example

> **ii**  openssh-server

A link that describes the dpkg flags
https://askubuntu.com/questions/18804/what-do-the-various-dpkg-flags-like-ii-rc-mean

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get purge nginx
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

I'm on ubuntu 14.04 and this worked for me.